# How to upload big videos to picasa using API

Tags: video, upload, picasa

I'm trying to upload big video file to picasa but not success yet.
I know that Picasa has a limitations : https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#VideoLimitations
But somehow, other movie sites still can upload HD videos to picasa. I think they use script to do that, they can't upload thousand of movies by themself.
So, anyone has clue to do this work ?